# How to run js code before everything in the page? I have session check in js and it should redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have session and js checks whether if it exists. It works fine, but dashboard page is seen for miliseconds, like a blink. But I need webpage to redirect before loading html code. How can I do this? I use vue js, even beforeCreate can't help.

Comment: If you are checking before loading each page you could do the check in the router with a beforeEach function. Either way you are probably going to want to do it in either the vue router or a beforeRouteEnter function if it's just for specific pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jayem163 said in the notes I would run the authentication verification in your router on `beforeRouteEnter` Below is a basic example. The router code will run before any render of your component. This way you don't have duplicate code for each route.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

// no authentication required -- OPTIONAL
const noAuthenticationRequired = (to, from, next) => {
  // in my apps right here I force logout. You don't want to go to a login page while logged in. But it's optional
  next()
}

// make sure user is authenticated
const requiresAuthentication = (to, from, next) => {
  // YOUR CHECK AUTH CODE WOULD GO HERE //
  if (success) {
    return next()   
  }

  // not successful
  next('/login')
}

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'dashboard',
      beforeEnter: requiresAuthentication, // this route will require authentication
      component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      beforeEnter: noAuthenticationRequired,
      component: () => import('./views/Login.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      beforeEnter: noAuthenticationRequired,
      component: () => import('./views/Register.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/password/forgot',
      name: 'forgotPassword',
      beforeEnter: noAuthenticationRequired,
      component: () => import('./views/ForgotPassword.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: `const noAuthenticationRequired = (to, from, next) => {
      if(sessionStorage.getItem("id"))
      window.location.replace("/#/profile");
    }` So now, its login page not using its layout, it's using the layout of dashboard, requiresAuthentication works correctly, but if I add noAuthentication there is a problem with layout

Comment: don't use `window.location.replace` use `next('/profile')`. Vue router doesn't work well with window location.replace. If you do the replace it won't mount correctly

Comment: 'const noAuthenticationRequired = (to, from, next) => {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("id"))
    next("/profile");
} {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Вход',
        meta: { layout: 'login' },
        component: login,
        beforeEnter: noAuthenticationRequired
    }' It is still failing